# How can I get a window object from new BrowserWindow() in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to reuse the window object? It may be necessary because the respective window may be generated dynamically.

```
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

app.on('ready', function(){
  var win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.loadURL 'file://' + __dirname + '/index.html';

  // now i want use the window object in my BroserWindow win
 window = win.getWindowObject; // like this
  window.document.write(); // i can use window object here
});
```

Comment: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions

Comment: sry, but I don't find which instance methods I can use it to get window object .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still there isn't a way to directly access window object, however the method [`BrowserWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) allows to do it indirect:

```js
let myWindow = new BrowserWindow(params);
myWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('window.anyWantedProperty')
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Be careful if you pass user input as this method allow code injection.