# How to use code coverage in Electron app which uses Angular?

Tags: angular, electron, ava, spectron, nyc

I write an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app (in TypeScript) that I test through [AVA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava) (in whose tests I use [Spectron](https://www.electronjs.org/spectron) to communicate with the app). The (browser) content of my app is generated by using [Angular](https://angular.io/). I execute the tests via:

```
npm run ava
```

All of this works great! Now I would like to put code-coverage on top of it. As listed above I use a variety of different frameworks and almost each one brings in their own solution.

- **AVA** recommends [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc).
- **Electron** has some user-tutorials which use [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--coverageboolean) + their coverage?
- Angular brings in their own [coverage](https://angular.io/guide/testing-code-coverage) which AFAIK can only be invoked by `ng test` so this is out too (I guess) because I have an electron app

I tried `nyc` but in its default configuration it only records the "main-process", but more importantly would be the (browser) content of the app. AFAIK `nyc` could instrument all `*.ts` files to add coverage info but to combine that with the Angular build tools doesn't seem to be easy/possible.

What would be a good way to solve this task? Any experiences on this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at how test coverage works. It generally consists of 2 parts: instrumenting and reporting.

- **Instrumenting** is basically wrapping lines of source code with additional counters that increment each time that line of code is executed
- **Reporting** is reading those counters and presenting/storing in a form of some report.

#### Instrumenting

`nyc` automatically instruments the node process it executes (and its child processes). However, in your case the actual code you want to measure is your compiled angular app that runs in a browser and not the Node process with the test runner itself.

What it means is that you need to instrument your app code yourself. For an Angular app it generally means you need a custom builder. Here is [a great article](https://lukas-klement.medium.com/implementing-code-coverage-with-angular-and-cypress-6ed08ed7e617) that explains how to do that (they talk about Cypress tests - but the instrumenting part is the same). Alternatively, you could pre-process your source files (via `nyc instrument`) before running `ng build`. This approach is featured in [another article](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/code-coverage-for-e2e-tests/) I googled.

### Reporting

Code instrumented as above would track its run metrics and store them in an istanbul-specific format in `window.__coverage__`. But how do we extract it? It doesn't seem like Spectron has built-in support for extracting those metrics (I will be glad to learn otherwise, but... github [issues/40](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/issues/40), [issues/261](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/issues/261)).

It sounds like our best try would be to implement it ourselves. One could access `window` object from Spectron's `BrowserWindow` (e.g. like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887766/2638874)). And store the content of its `__coverage__` property in a file after each test. You could use @cypress/code-coverage [source code](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/master/support.js#L120) as an example of such an approach (apparently it's for Cypress, not for Spectron - but the general idea is the same).

Comment: That is an excellent answer and the links you found are the cherry on the top. Thank you so much! I applied the bounty and will give it a few more hours before I accept the answer. Thanks again!